# Set of products of Number N is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I show that the Set of the products of a number is countable?
For example, if F the set of the products of number 5 (minus 0(zero)) F={5,-5,10,-10,15,-15,...}, how can it be proved that it's a countable set?

EDIT: By countable, I mean that set F with the set N(natural numbers with zero), can be a bijective function.

Comment: How do you define countable?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. I guess what you asked is how to prove the set $m\mathbb{Z}$ is countable. Am I correct?

Comment: By countable, I mean that set F with the set N(natural numbers with zero), can be a bijective function.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a bijection from $N$ to $F$.

Example: If $F={0,2,4,6,...}$, then $f(n) = 2n$ will do. Just show that it's a bijection.